# C++/CLI Wrapper class track unmanaged object pointers

Tags: c++, c++-cli, clr, wrapper

I have an unmanaged C++ class `SRWindow` that I want to wrap in C++/CLI. The wrapper class is called `SEWindow` and has a constructor that also creates an `SRWindow` object:

```
public ref class SEWindow
{
private:
    SRWindow* nativeInstance;

public:
    SEWindow(int widthPX, int heightPX, String^ name, bool fullscreen)
    {
        //name -> nativeName
        nativeInstance = new SRWindow(widthPX, heightPX, nativeName, fullscreen);
    }

    SEWindow(SRWindow* window) : nativeInstance(window)
    {
    }

    !SEWindow()
    {
        delete nativeInstance;
    }

    //Other wrapped methods

};
```

Objects of the `SRWindow` class are passed between other C++ library classes, for example to the `SRButtonLayout` class, which has an `addBinding(std::function<void(int key, SRWindow* window)>)` method. To use this method in C++/CLI, the passed `SRWindow* window` object must be wrapped in `gcnew SEWindow(window)`.

```
public delegate void KeyEvent(Key key, SEWindow^ window);

void ManagedAddBinding(SRButtonLayout* nativeInstance, KeyEvent^ ievent)
{
    gcroot<KeyEvent^> wrapper(ievent);
    nativeInstance->addBinding(
        [wrapper](int key, SRWindow* window) {
            wrapper->Invoke(static_cast<Key>(key), gcnew SEWindow(window));
        }
    );
}
```

This causes several `SEWindow` wrappers to reference the same unmanaged object and if one of them is caught by the garbage collector, the unmanaged object will also be deleted, even though other objects are still referencing it.

It may be possible to fix this issue using a map that counts the number of occurrences of each pointer, or in general a map that links a wrapper object with an unmanaged object based on its pointer, but this would be inefficient and seems too complicated for something so basic. Would it be possible to keep better track of unmanaged objects, so that they could only be deleted when they are no longer referenced?

Comment: Why not let `std::shared_ptr`s do the job? You'd create one for the single instance to pass around, and provide it to the managed wrapper constructors (as reference should suffice to prevent unnecessary reference counting), which would assign it to another shared pointer instance in the class (non-reference). On disposing you'd just reset the shared pointer not to hold any element any more, and the last shared pointer holding the object would then delete it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do it that way because my C++/CLI project wraps a C++ library that I have limited access to. This would require modifying virtually the entire library to pass data everywhere via `shared_ptr`s. A similar solution that would be simpler to implement would be to manually count the number of occurrences of an object. This could be achieved by creating an `int instanceCount` field in each library class, which would be incremented when a wrapper object is created. However, this is not an ideal solution, as it still requires library interference, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: No, no need to modify any third party code, just your own: At some point you'd receive that third party object from the library – and you'd assign it to an initial `std::shared_ptr` – which you'd use to initialise all your `SEWindow` wrappers. Whenever you need to pass the object back into the library you simply fetch the raw pointer out of the shared one via `thePointer.get()`! Finally: If this library does not expect you to `delete` the objects, but instead call a specific library function to free it again (like most C libraries) then peek at the second template parameter of

Comment: [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) – it allows you to provide a custom deleter type – and instead of deleting the object such one would call that library function…  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451775/smart-pointer-custom-deleter) might shed some light on how to write such a custom deleter. I recommend to have your own typedef then to avoid repeating code like e.g. `using SRWindowSharedPointer = std::shared_ptr<SRWindow, SRWindowDeleter>;`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to re-invent the wheel, [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) already exists exactly for such scenarios! Using such one your code might look like this:

```
// some general conversion function, independent from SEWindow class:
std::string nativeString(String^ managed);

public ref class SEWindow
{
public:
    SEWindow(int widthPX, int heightPX, String^ name, bool fullscreen)
        : nativeInstance
          (
              std::make_shared<SRWindow>
              (
                  widthPX, heightPX, nativeString(name), fullscreen
              )
          )
    { }

    SEWindow(std::shared_ptr<SRWindow>& window)
    // reference:                     ^
    // avoids unnecessary copy and with it, reference counting
        : nativeInstance(window) // <- reference counting only here is fine
    { }

    !SEWindow()
    {
        // just reset the pointer; if this is the last one
        // holding the object it will delete it
        nativeInstance.reset();
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<SRWindow> nativeInstance;
};
```

(Entirely untested code; if you find a bug, please fix yourself…)

If you now need to pass around the raw pointers to any third party libraries: No problem, you can always get one from the shared pointer via `std::shared_ptr::get` function, e.g. like:

```
void library::f(SRWindow* w);

void SEWindow::f()
{
    library::f(nativeInstance.get());
}
```

Finally (general advice; as you seem to construct the `SRWindow` instances on your own anyway, it might not be relevant in the specific case) if you retrieve the objects to be wrapped from one of the libraries and are not expected to `delete` them, but instead call some dedicated library function (or simply C's `free`), which is the case with many C libraries, then you have two options: Either still wrap these objects into a `std::shared_ptr`, but provide a custom deleter (-> the second, defaulted template argument) – in which case I recommend using a type alias for, e.g.:

```
using SRWindowSharedPointer = std::shared_ptr<SRWindow, SRWindowDeleter>;
```

– or you write yet another custom native wrapper calling the function in its destructor. This latter one you'd use then in the shared pointers. Note, though, that this latter approach – which might be slightly simpler to implement – introduces yet another level of indirection, thus I'd rather go with the custom deleter. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451775/smart-pointer-custom-deleter) might be helpful on writing such one.

Comment: That's not quite what I meant. The library I'm using never creates an `SRWindow` object by itself - it's only created when the `SEWindow(int widthPX, int heightPX, String^ name, bool fullscreen)` constructor is called. Then, I can start displaying the window using `nativeInstance->DisplayLoop()`. I can also create a new object of class `SRButtonLayout` that contains the lambdas that are executed inside of the display loop when a button is pressed. Since the program can have several windows, a pointer to the window in which the button was pressed is passed to the lambda.

Comment: I can't use the received pointer to the `SRWindow` as an `std::shared_ptr` because it is returned by the library, not my C++/CLI code. The only way I've come up with to identify this pointer is either to assign it in a static map to a specific wrapper, or to modify the library so that its objects contain an occurrence counter for use by C++/CLI

Comment: These two comments sound contradicting. Once you create a `SRWindow` inside the constructor, then again it only comes from library. So which one now? Or both? How many instances do you create? As mentioned already, a custom deleter would always allow to return the instance(s) to the library, which could do with it whatever it wants. You *can* retrieve such an object *once* from the library and store it in an initial shared pointer; as long as you are creating new instances of `SEWindow`s you pass that pointer to them, once done reset the initial one or just let it run out of scope.

Comment: @BSP0 [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/v4TzEWvfr) a demonstration how using shared pointers *might* look like… Note: Pure C++, default destructor cleans up. In the C++/CLI code you'd yet add resetting the pointer as already done in the answer already.

Comment: These comments do not contradict each other, it works like this:
1. `SEWindow` creates an instance of `SRWindow`
2. A lambda created from a c# delegate is passed to `SRWindow`
3. In the c++/cli code, the native method of `SRWindow` class - `DisplayLoop()` (`nativeInstance->DisplayLoop()`) is executed, which is defined in the library and I can't modify it. 
4. The `DisplayLoop()` method of the unmanaged `SRWindow` class executes the lambda, passing itself as an argument using `this` (which means it now comes from the library, despite the fact that this object was created in c++/cli)

Comment: Then I do not see which is your problem. All you need to make sure that each instance of `SRWinow` is maintained by either a single unique_ptr or by at least one shared_ptr, and in case you need a raw pointer fetch it out of the smart pointer via `get()` function. That's it. If you draw a [mre] how usage really looks like (including multiple SEWindows sharing the same SRWindow) I can elaborate further. Side note: In case of 'window's (-> GUI?) it appears suspicious to me that multple SEWindows should share the same SRWindow (though if DisplayLoop is re-entrant it might not impose problems).